# Wait for async function in foreach

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project, I tryout different Ip adresses for connection. If I cannot connect, I will switch to the next Ip

```
foreach(var handler in webHandlers)
{
    if(handler.TryConnect())
    {
        handler.Init();
        break;
    }
}
```

Handler class:

```
bool finished = false;
bool returnval = false;

public bool TryConnect()
{
    StartCoroutine(TryConnection);
    while(!finished) { }
    return returnval;
}
IEnummerator TryConnection()
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("url");
    www.timeout = 5;
    yield return wwww.SendWebRequest();
    if(www.isNetworkError)
    {
        returnval = false;
    }
    {
        returnval = true;
    }
    finished = true;
}
```

If there is a connection, it works instantly. But if it cannot find it, unity crashes. The value of finished never seems to change. It doesnt matter that the game blocks, because this should be finished before starting the game.

My question is, how can I solve this, where I wait for the result of this coroutine.

Comment: You don't synchronise access to `finished`

Comment: Do you think this is necessary `while(!finished) { }`

Comment: @zerkms how do you mean synchonize acces fo finished?

Comment: @BaasBartMans you access a variable from different threads and one of those modifies it, it's a data race.

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking your main thread when you use `while(!finished){}`. Better You should move your coroutine in another script. ie Where your handlers is available. And call for each handler in the coroutine. If the connection is not available then move on to next handler in next coroutine instance.

You can check the modified function. The function is rough snippet based on your code which keeps on checking for connection until either it connects to any one of the handlers or runs out of the handlers.

```
public IEnumerator TryConnection(int index)
{
    if (handlers.count > index)
    {
        //Get next handler here
        Handler handler = handlers[index];
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(handler.url);
        www.timeout = 5;
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        if (www.isNetworkError)
        {
            StartCoroutine(TryConnection(index++));
        }
        else
        {
            handler.init();
        }
    }        
}
```

Remember to move the TryConnection to the place where you have the List of handlers available.

Comment: I understand the way of thinking. But I will still need to wait for the script that handles all handlers to finish before starting the game

Comment: So what you want to do? You cannot and should not block the main thread using while. Either that or use threads to check out the connection simultaneously but UnityWebRequest can only by run in main thread and not in any other threads. If you try that it will throw error. Better would be put a loading screen to wait for connection. That is what the usual process is. Or do you want to test all of your connections on handlers simultaneously? If that is the case then change the function to parse with handler. If the connection is true and no error then handler.init() will initialise else it wont

Comment: You said you want to "I tryout different Ip adresses for connection. If I cannot connect, I will switch to the next Ip". What exactly are you trying to do? Try the IP one by one or all together?

Comment: I dont want to try everything at once because the first thing that works should be the way (i ordened my list by best to worst). I Actualy want to block the main thread because the game should not start before this is all set. In a bigger project I could do a seperate loading scene where I wait for all this to finish, but this project is so small that I will not do that

Answer (score 0):

I actualy found a way that was a lot simpeler and cleaner

```
public bool TryConnect()
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
```

Since it is not run on a coroutine, the code just waits until the response is recieved. This is also a lot quicker than unities version. Since all of this is called in the main thread, the game waits for the response before even starting up. The timeout on this is a second at most so it doesnt hold up the game (like a connection timeout from unity does)